# Match empty lines in a file with 'grep'

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

Why does

```
grep -c '^\n' myfile.txt
```

*return 0* when there are empty lines in the file?

If there is an empty line, it starts with a new line, right?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The regular expression to match the end of the line is `$`, not `\n` (since `grep` works a line at a time, it ignores the newlines between lines).

```
grep -c '^$' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Okay. Got it. I dint know that grep ignores newlines between lines. Thanks!!

Comment: To be precise, `$` is the RE character to match the end of a string, not the end of a line. grep just happens to treat each line of input as a separate string so with grep each string end (`$`) occurs where the line ended but other tools behave differently. `$` always means `the end of the string` in all tools though.

Comment: @EdMorton In contexts where there can't be multiple lines, EOL and EOS are equivalent.  Anything that processes only one line at a time is that context.

Comment: @Barmar I understand where you're coming from, I was just addressing the statements that `The regular expression to match the end of the line is $` and `grep ... ignores the newlines between lines` which I felt could easily be misunderstood.

Comment: Be careful, the `-o` `grep` option ignores empty lines, it seems.

Comment: @F8ER GNU grep ignores empty lines, BSD grep doesn't.

Comment: Just to clarify. GNU grep doesn't ignore them without `-o` option and `^$` pattern.

Comment: @F8ER The test I tried was `grep -o '.*'`. GNU grep ignored the empty lines, BSD grep showed them.

Answer (score 10):

grep and count empty lines like this:

```
grep -c "^$" myfile.txt
```

As `\n` is considered end of line you need to use line start and line end `"^$"`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers with `-c` are correct.

If you want to see what number is the empty line in the file:

```
grep -n '^$' myfile.txt
```

For example:

```
grep -n '^$' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
4751:
34329:
50383:
99361:
154363:
231236:
562997:
2459758:
14344383:
14344384:
14344385:
```

(If you want to remove them: `sed -i '/^$/d' myfile.txt` )

:)